# How to resize embedded word file properly in word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, embedded

I love to embed an external file into Word .docx file since that helps me to "outsource" the content - I don't have to put the whole big content into one-only file.

Below is how we can do such embedding.

[image]

[image]

My issue is I cannot resize the embedded Word object - while embedding for PDF works great.

Here is [one sample Word file](https://db.tt/0walpndN) that has 1) [embedded PDF file](https://db.tt/sRrUIAAP) and 2) [embedded Word file](https://db.tt/CguGMLQg).

You can view the outcome as below snapshot.

So how can we resize that Word embedded object? A [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=How%20to%20resize%20embedded%20word%20file%20properly%20in%20word%202013&oq=How%20to%20resize%20embedded%20word%20file%20properly%20in%20word%202013&aqs=chrome..69i57.176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) seems to be not very helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: I just tried in word 2019, and inserted object word file can be easily resized. Seems they have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. right click on the object and select "picture." The "Format Object"dialog box appears.
2. Select the "Size" tab and adjust your height/width to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a hackish solution, but it's the best I've been able to do. In trying to embed an OpenDocuments text file in Microsoft Word 16 I did the following:

1. Insert tab > Text section: Object, Object > OpenDocument Text > OK
2. Home tab > Font section: size (let's say 6 - whatever size keeps it from wrapping)
3. 10 (font size in the main document) - 6 = 4
4. 4 / 6 = .66667 = 67%
5. Add my text > save > close
6. in the main document, I followed @Alex's answer and "right click[ed] on the object and select[ed] "picture." The "Format Object"dialog box appears."
7. "Select the "Size" tab and adjust your height/width to the desired size." << here, I added the percentage I got in step 4 to 100 and it looks great.

I hope this helps - If not the OP, at least somebody.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to embed the document and have it look like an icon. This is more weildy for some use cases.

Tested on Word 2013:

1. Click Insert -> Object
2. "Create from File" tab
3. Select your file and check "Display as icon"
4. Click OK

Solution found on [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-a-File-Into-a-Word-Document).

**Bonus**: For lightning fast embedding, use the super-simple keyboard shortcut :`Alt+N`, `J`, `J`, `Shift+Alt+F`, `Shift+Alt+A`, `Shift+Alt+B`, (choose your file,) `Enter`.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility:

1. Decrease/increase the zoom size (which will increase/decrease the size of all the icons and the text).
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Change the text font size to a smaller/larger size to put the text back to the size it was before the zoom size was changed.